# Percentage margin-bottom Media query not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been building a small image lightbox and im trying to make the width of the image and its containing div 100% of the page when the screen size is 600px, but my media query wont execute for some reason. Does this have to do with the margin-bottom being a percentage?
Thanks
https://jsfiddle.net/egL1offh/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .lightboxCenter{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 17.5%;
    margin-top: auto;
    top: 25%;
  }

  .lightboxCenter>img{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 17.5%;
    margin-top: auto;
    top: 25%;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See I couldn't find anything inside of `.lightboxCenter` i.e. it is `empty` and this what you are declaring in `media query` `.lightboxCenter > img`, so it won't works, as you are selecting a `child element`, but it's a `empty div`. `img tag` is present inside `.imageGallery`, so you need to use that to scale your `image 100%` at `max-width of 600px` as below,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.imageGallery{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.imageGallery > img{
  width:100%;
}
}
```

Comment: @Kempster I gave above solution as you are using > css selector.